# How does one implement action masking?

Tags: tensorflow, multitasking, reinforcement-learning

The [Actor Mimic](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06342v4.pdf) paper talks about implementing an action-masking procedure. I quote

> While playing a certain game, we
>   mask out AMN action outputs that are not valid for that game and take the softmax over only the subset of valid actions

Does anyone have an idea about how this action masking can be implemented in say Tensorflow? In specifc, how would one take a softmax only over specified subset of actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have a valid state tensor which contains ones and zeros.

`is_valid = [1, 0, 1, ...]`

and then you have an actions tensor on which you want to take the softmax over those values which are valid.  You could do the following.

`(tf.exp(actions) * is_valid) / (tf.reduce_sum(tf.exp(actions) * is_valid) + epsilon)`

In this case the is_valid is masking out the invalid values in the sum.  I would also add a small epsilon to the division for the sake of numerical stability so you can never divide by zero.

Comment: With this solution you introduce numerical instabilities. Tensorflow explicitly discourages users from using such constructs.

Comment: One might also try `(tf.exp(actions) * is_valid) / (tf.reduce_sum(tf.exp(actions) * is_valid) + (1 - is_valid))` if they cared about extreme precision. That way epsilon doesn't fuzz the values you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

You should rely on the built in softmax function. i.e. you should first mask the invalid action in your tensor by using a [boolean_mask](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/boolean_mask) and then apply the softmax function.

(The solution provided by [chasep255](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2876799/chasep255) has numerical issues.)